# How can I display user data (profile, email) through Azure AD OAuth? - Expo App

Tags: react-native, api, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, expo

In my Expo App, I authenticate my users through an Azure AD Login using useAuthRequest, and I pass in the scopes `["openid", "profile", "name"]` on my request, as you can see in the extraction below:

```
const [request, response, promptAsync] = useAuthRequest(
  {
    clientId: `${config.CLIENT_ID}`,
    clientSecret: `${config.CLIENT_SECRET}`,
    scopes: [ 'openid', 'profile', 'email'],
    prompt: 'login',
    redirectUri: "msauth.my-bundle-id://auth",
    returnUrl: "msauth.com.my-bundle-id://auth",
  },
  discovery
  );
```

How can I display the authenticated users email, name and picture in my app?
(The login itself is working correctly)

Comment: Hey, are you already discover how to display user data?

Comment: Hey @haksatrya-bhaswara ! Yes, the solution is right here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72044215/getting-user-data-through-an-azure-ad-oauth-login-react-native-expo-app